# Node/Webpack 4 - how to use the root domain

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, netlify

I need to use the root domain of a page in a view that i inject in the html via javascript:

```
<meta property="og:url" name="twitter:url" itemprop="url" content="<%- root_domain %><%- local_path %>">
```

The problem is that today I kind of do it the "hard-coded" way, as I set it always equal to `https://www.example.com` but in our Netlify CI the root domain change son every build, like `deploy-preview-118--xyz-434545.netlify.com` on one build, then `deploy-preview-119--xyz-434545.netlify.com`, and so on...

So I would like NOT to set hard-coded the root_domain to https:://www.example.com.

In a node app with webpack self-conscious of the root domain ? Is there a method that if I use always give the current root domain ? Coming from the Rails ecosystem, we have `root_path` method which always equal to the root domain (here it would be `example.com`, `deploy-preview-118--xyz-434545.netlify.com`, `deploy-preview-119--xyz-434545.netlify.com`...).

Not sure it plays a role on this question, but we use https://github.com/markdalgleish/static-site-generator-webpack-plugin plugin so we have a locals.path method but it gives us everything AFTER the root domain while what we want is the root domain.

Comment: what if you remove `<%- root_domain %>` altogether and only use the `<%- local_path %>`, or are relative urls not supported in this context?

Comment: does not work. If I leave just content="<%- local_path %>", I'll see for the homepage content="", and for the page example.com/es/foo content="/es/foo". This works well on metas using the href attribute, but on metas using the content attribute, you need an absolute path=you must have the whole url. so I need to inject the root domain.

Comment: plus I'm sure I will need in other occasions to be able to access the root domain :)

Comment: then the only other option i can think of is to use the deploy url variable in your pipeline and reading it from the webpack configuration. see https://www.netlify.com/docs/continuous-deployment/#build-environment-variables.

`URL`, `DEPLOY_URL` or `DEPLOY_PRIME_URL`

Comment: nice, had missed these methods on netlify thanks

Comment: testing it right now.

Comment: I am using it in a .js file like const rootUrl  = $DEPLOY_PRIME_URL;, but getting error: ReferenceError: $DEPLOY_PRIME_URL is not defined Do you think it's usable in any jf file or only on netlify toml files ? Not clear to me.

Comment: try `process.env.DEPLOY_PRIME_URL`, otherwise `console.log(process.env)` to see what other environmental variables are set.

Comment: if it turns out its one of the other URL options mentioned in documentation you should be able to see in the logs which one it is based on `process.env`

Comment: yes i see it in my build logs, but not working now in my js. i must debug but your answer seems fine. If you post a formal answer I'll upvote. thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem, and thanks! will formulate a formal answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on our discussion above.

After looking at Netlify's documentation, They provide several built in environmental variables which include, `URL`, `DEPLOY_URL` and `DEPLOY_PRIME_URL`

Reference: [netlify-build-environment-variables](https://www.netlify.com/docs/continuous-deployment/#build-environment-variables.)

You should be able to use these in your build to set the `<%- root_domain %>` variable.

Environmental variables can be accessed in `node.js` using `process.env`.
So in your webpack config would pass root url to the static site generator.

```
plugins: [
    new StaticSiteGeneratorPlugin({
      locals: {
        root_domain: process.env.DEPLOY_PRIME_URL || 'https://www.example.com'
      }
    })
]
```

where `https://www.example.com` would be used for local development or in the absence of an environmental variable.